# What is the difference between a boundary *existing* (or rather, *not* existing) and a boundary *being empty*?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, submanifold, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm confused about the concept of a "boundary" in topology – specifically, in studying manifolds. What is the difference between a boundary *existing* (or rather, *not* existing) and a boundary *being empty*? To put it more clearly, if a boundary of a manifold is empty, then does that still imply that a boundary exists?

Comment: Yes, here, I would essentially translate ‘exist’ to ‘non-empty’. Where/how exactly did you see this usage? Note that the boundary of a set in a given topological space need not coincide with the manifold boundary. For example, the topological boundary of $(0,1)$ as a subset of the ambient $\Bbb{R}$ is $\text{bd}_{\Bbb{R}}\left((0,1)\right)=\{0,1\}$, whereas $(0,1)$ being an open subset of the smooth manifold $\Bbb{R}$ can be considered a smooth manifold in its own right in which case it has empty boundary (i.e the usual definition of ‘smooth manifold’ is satisfied).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I saw it in the context of this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4755246/356308 question.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I'm not sure if I'm understanding your comment/point correctly, but it seems to me that it's referring to something that I've noticed as I started studying topology: the concept of "boundary" in the context that it is usually encountered outside of / before studying manifolds, such as the "boundary" of an open set, as you gave it your example, is different to the the concept of "boundary" in the context of manifolds. [...]

Comment: [...] I noticed that this point is even made explicitly on Wikipedia's "Boundary (topology)" page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology) : Notice that (at the time of writing this comment) there's a note at the very top/beginning of the page that says "This article is about boundaries in general topology. It is not to be confused with boundary of a manifold or boundary of a locally closed subset", which links to these https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_closed_subset two articles.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Perhaps you/someone can post an answer that explains/incorporates/contrasts these concepts and their distinctions – that would be very clarifying.

Comment: I could, but really these are all textbook definitions, so you should read the appropriate textbooks to clarify them. For example in your linked question, you need to (as mentioned there) understand two phrases “manifold with boundary” (note don’t think of this as three seprate words; think of it as one big concept expressed with 3 words) vs “manifold”.. And given that you already see the different wikipedia pages, you should read the definitions carefully and analyze the differences and use any and all examples you have.

Comment: @peek-a-boo are manifolds $\equiv$ manifolds-with-empty-boundary

Comment: I think non-empty is implied when people talk about existence. Empty set always exists anyway by an axiom of set theory

Comment: @rych for our purposes, yes, though once people know what they're talking about, for brevity they may use "manifold" to mean "manifold with boundary" or "manifold with empty boundary" and to let context determine the meaning,